# Append Dataframe values in Dictionary by matching Dictionary key with Dataframe Column name Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to add values in dictionary of list by matching column name of dataframe with dictionary key.
my value is getting added in dictionary but its adding for each in every key which is present in dictionary not to specific matched key.

how can I solve this?

This is the dataset:

```
Df1 = 
    15550  15600  15650  15700  15750  15800  15850  15900  15950  16000  16050  16100  16150  16200  16250  16300
    -588  -9281   -896 -14801   5710  53666  72235   8786  11873 -34997  12585   1022 -13363 -48165  -4204 -21011
```

```
dict1 = {15550: [-588], 15600: [-9281], 15650: [-896], 15700: [-14801], 15750: [5710], 15800: [53666], 15850: [72235], 15900: [8786]}
```

```
alldata_dict = {'PE_15300': [0], 'PE_15350': [0], 'PE_15400': [0], 'PE_15450': [0], 'PE_15500': [0], 'PE_15550': [0], 'PE_15600': [0], 'PE_15650': [0], 'PE_15700': [0], 'PE_15750': [0], 'PE_15800': [0], 'PE_15850': [0], 'PE_15900': [0]}
```

I'm trying below code:

```
for i in alldata_dict:
    col_index = 0
    col_name = df1.columns[col_index]
    col_value = oppe_dict[col_name].values[0]
        
    to_string = str(col_name)
    to_int = int(col_value)    
    if to_string in i:
        k = int(to_int)
        alldata_dict[i].append(k)
                    
    print(alldata_dict)
```

I want to iterate this code for all the values present in Df1

Comment: Does `alldata_dict.keys()` have different values ​​than `Df1.columns`, excluding the 'PE_' prefix?

Comment: @Riqq no, `alldata_dict` has some extra keys than `Df1`, but it has all the values which are present in `Df1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating some data

```
alldata_dict = {'PE_15300': [0], 'PE_15350': [0], 'PE_15400': [0], 'PE_15450': [0], 'PE_15500': [0], 'PE_15550': [0], 'PE_15600': [0], 'PE_15650': [0], 'PE_15700': [0], 'PE_15750': [0], 'PE_15800': [0], 'PE_15850': [0], 'PE_15900': [0]}
df = pd.DataFrame({
    15550: [-588],
    15600: [-9281],
    15650: [-896]
})
```

The df data:

```
   15550  15600  15650
0   -588  -9281   -896
```

The solution:

```
for column in df.columns:
    for value in df[column].values:
        alldata_dict['PE_'+str(column)].append(value)
```

Result:

```
{'PE_15300': [0], 'PE_15350': [0], 'PE_15400': [0], 'PE_15450': [0], 'PE_15500': [0], 'PE_15550': [0, -588], 'PE_15600': [0, -9281], 'PE_15650': [0, -896], 'PE_15700': [0], 'PE_15750': [0], 'PE_15800': [0], 'PE_15850': [0], 'PE_15900': [0]}
```

Comment: Thank you @Riqq but now all `df` values are getting added to `alldata_dict` every key

Comment: if I run only your code then its giving the exact output like I want but when I'm applying this to my code then its not working. 
`alldata_dict` is created by using `fromkeys` method, does this impact on code?

Comment: it wasn't working because of `fromkeys` . Thanks @Riqq

Comment: I'm glad it helped, and I'm sorry I wasn't able to support you earlier.